# Como usar função Max() e Count() juntas?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Fala pessoal! Estou treinando um subselect com having usando as funções MAX E COUNT juntas, mas o SQLServer está me retornando um erro chamado: 
"Não é possível executar uma função de agregação em uma expressão que contenha uma agregação ou uma subconsulta."

Geralmente faço os scripts no oracle sql developer não sei se é algum erro de sintaxe, alguém pode me ajudar? Segue abaixo o comando executado:

```
select clfDescricao
from classificacaofiscal c, notafiscaleletronica n
where c.clfCFO = n.NFE_cnatOP
group by clfDescricao
having count(n.NFE_id) = (select max(count(n.NFE_id))
from classificacaofiscal c, notafiscaleletronica n
where c.clfCFO = n.NFE_cnatOP)
```

Comment: Tente explicar o que deseja obter.

Comment: Qual DB engine? Vc menciona tanto o SQL Server quanto o Oracle. Para facilitar a reprodução do problema, tente criar um fiddle em http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: E como dito anteriormente, explique o que deseja obter. Procure não se focar em como está a fazê-lo. O erro pode estar na forma de implementar o que se deseja. Não me parece fazer sentido usar `select max(count(n.NFE_id))`, por exemplo.

Comment: Teste: `select count(n.NFE_id)
from classificacaofiscal c, notafiscaleletronica n
where c.clfCFO = n.NFE_cnatOP` com seus dados e avalie o resultado. Depois verifique se faz sentido utilizar a função max neste select.

Comment: Pessoal eu estou fazendo o script no Oracle, estou tentando responder a seguinte pergunta:
Qual CFOP teve o maior número de notas fiscais registradas?

Comment: Uma solução seria você fazer um count agrupando por CFOP, ordenar em ordem decrescente e pegar apenas o primeiro. Neste caso você pode não obter a informação completa se existirem mais de um CFOP com a mesma quantidade. Outro solução seria pegar os count em um subselect e no select mais externo pegar o max sobre o resultado do subselect.

Answer (score 1):

Li pelos comentários que você está tentando fazer isso em Oracle.
Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
/*Cria o agrupamento por descrição*/
WITH dados AS (
SELECT clfdescricao, 
       MAX(COUNT(n.nfe_id)) cnt
  FROM classificacaofiscal c, notafiscaleletronica n
 WHERE c.clfcfo = n.nfe_cnatop
 GROUP BY clfdescricao)

/*Retorna apenas o que tiver maior número de notas*/
SELECT clfdescricao 
  FROM dados 
 WHERE cnt = (SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM dados)
```

Dessa primeira forma, você perde um pouco de performance, porém deixa o código mais fácil de ser compreendido. Então, é valido fazer uma avaliação do volume de dados, para ver qual será o impacto.

No seu caso, basicamente você só esqueceu de colocar o `group by` dentro do seu `sub-select`, como não há ligação com a `query` de fora, você poderia executa-la de forma avulsa e checar o motivo de não ter funcionado.

Segue o exemplo utilizando a função `HAVING`:

```
SELECT clfdescricao
  FROM classificacaofiscal c, notafiscaleletronica n
 WHERE c.clfcfo = n.nfe_cnatop
 GROUP BY clfdescricao
HAVING COUNT(n.nfe_id) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(n.nfe_id))
                            FROM classificacaofiscal  c,
                                 notafiscaleletronica n
                           WHERE c.clfcfo = n.nfe_cnatop
                           GROUP BY clfdescricao)
```